# Show that $ (\pi(g)\phi)(v)=\phi({^t}gv) $ defines a representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $ G=SL_2(\mathbb{C}) $ and consider the action of $ G $ on the space of smooth functions on column vectors $ v \in \mathbb{C^2} $ given by: $ (\pi(g)\phi)(v)=\phi({^t}gv)  $

**Question 1: Show that $ \pi $ defines a representation**

I must show that $\pi(gh)=\pi(g)\pi(h)$ for $g, h \in G$

I have had a go at playing around with the formula but am not sure how to manipulate $ (\pi(g)\phi)(v)=\phi({^t}gv)  $

Could you give me some pointers please?

Comment: There is not much to do but apply the definition. See what each side does to some arbitrary vector $v$ and check that they are the same.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you help me see what is the effect of say $(\pi(g)\phi)(v)$ as I am really struggling on this very basic concept. If you could guide me through that would be perfect

Comment: That is not one of the things you should be looking at (you have already written up what that is after all). You need to write up what $\pi(gh)(v)$ is, using that definition.

Comment: It is just that I do not understand what $(\pi(g)\phi)(v)$ does. So $\pi(g)=\pi(gh)\pi^{-1}(h)$. Plugging this into the first equation, I get $(\pi(gh)\pi^{-1}(h)\phi)(v)$

Comment: Sorry, I wrote up the wrong thing. You need to see what $\pi(gh)$ does to some arbitrary function $\phi$, so you should write up what the function $\pi(gh)\phi$ does to some arbitrary vector $v$, using the definition.

Comment: how do you define ${^t}g$ ?

Comment: @KonKan this is the transpose of g

Answer (score 0):

$$(g.(h.\phi))(v)=(h.\phi)(^tg.v)=\phi(^th.(^tg.v))=\phi((^th^tg).v)=\phi(^t(gh).v)=((gh).\phi)(v).$$